# Is it good practise to have the class name as a prefix in Django model?

Tags: database-design, django

**I wrote a model in this format in Django:**

```
class Block(models.Model):
    block_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    block_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    block_content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    block_change_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=datetime.now())
    block_published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.now())
```

Is this a useful practise to have **`block_`** (or whatever other model name) for each or does it just add length to the field names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not.

Think about it, where would you ever need them?

- Not when you create the model: you know what model are you creating.
- Not inside the model itself: you know where you are too.
- Nor when accessing the model later: you still know the type of the model, unless you don't care about the type, in which case prefixes will be only an annoyance.

Imagine a model such as:

```python
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Would `person.person_first_name` make more sense than `person.first_name`? Would `Person` ever contain a `first_name` which is not the first name of the person, so that you'll end up for example with:

```python
class Person(models.Model):
    person_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    persons_husband_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    persons_first_child_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    persons_pet_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    administrator_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

You might have already seen such code, but code like this is indicative of a complete misunderstanding of OOP by the author.

Another aspect to consider is **inheritance**. You may have:

```python
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Employee(Person):
    pass

class Freelancer(Person):
    pass
```

Following the convention where model members are prefixed with the class name, you'll end up *expecting* `employee.employee_first_name`, but finding `employee.person_first_name`, which is counter-intuitive. If you start overriding members, things become even messier.

Finally, if you need a more authoritative source, more specific to Django models, look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/). The example above is copied from it. You'll see that other examples don't have such prefixes either.

Comment: I thought it might improve readability but you are indeed correct, it does get confusing.

Comment: It will be even more annoying if you have to access the database directly using sql, as Django already adds the app names to tables.